# newtxtext problem on OpenSUSE

Tags: newtx

Here is a problem I have with the .cls file of the AGU Journals.

Unfortunately, the file agujournal.cls requires packages that are not included in Tex Live for OpenSUSE Linux, my operating system: \RequirePackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}.

In fact, I get everytime the error 'File newtxtext.sty not found'.

I am also unable to install new special fonts, which is the solution that Ubuntu users discuss on internet, because that's not possible in OpenSUSE.

Can you help me in solving this issue?

Marcello

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Well, this package is included in TeX Live. Are you sure that you have installed the full TeX Live?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSUSE splits up the TeX Live distribution into separate RPM packages.  The LaTeX packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` are found in the [`texlive-newtx`](https://software.opensuse.org/package/texlive-newtx) RPM.  You can install this RPM in various ways:

1. Use the "Software Manager" application from YaST.
2. Use Zypper from the command line (`sudo zypper in texlive-newtx`).
3. Point your browser to openSUSE's [Package Search](https://software.opensuse.org/search) and search for `texlive-newtx`. On the [results page](https://software.opensuse.org/package/texlive-newtx), use the "Direct Install" link if the page correctly guessed your version of openSUSE. Otherwise, follow the "Show other versions" link and then follow the "1 click install" link next to the package listed for your version of openSUSE.

Alternatively, you can forget about openSUSE's own distribution of TeX Live (which I find lags behind the official releases) and instead [download and install it manually](https://www.tug.org/texlive/).  If you do this, be sure to remove the openSUSE RPMs, and install the [`texlive-dummy_install`](https://software.opensuse.org/package/texlive-dummy_install) package in its place.  (This package fools openSUSE into thinking that the openSUSE version of TeX Live is installed.  It's important because the openSUSE version of TeX Live is a dependency for some other important system packages.)